# Does it makes sense to pause a DAG that has Schedule set to None?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to Airflow and have a hard time to figure for what `Pause a DAG` is used for.
If our dags are set only for `manual trigger` does it makes sense to pause these kind of DAGs?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly! Airflow DAGs that are configured with a `schedule_interval` of `None` *could* be executed by manual intervention through the UI, getting triggered by another DAG via the [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/triggerdagrunoperator), or even through an API call. If any of these actions happen, you could prevent the DAG from running by pausing it.

Another situation for pausing DAGs could be if a DAG fails frequently for whatever reason or has some flawed logic which requires manual intervention to fix data affected by the DAG processing, you can pause the DAG to keep it from executing even if the DAG has a regular `schedule_interval`.

There are other scenarios but pausing DAGs is helpful if you want to prevent DAG execution caused by an expected or even unexpected triggering.

Comment: But if we take in consideration that we want to run the DAG only via API/Manually or trigger by another dag. Is there other purpose to pause it? Does pausing a DAG usually helps when you want to "remove" it from scheduler?